Why can't I import the rest of my project in the unit tests?
so I have created a project much like turtle and everything in the code is working. I have now come to the unit tests though and when I am using the import command ("using") it doesn't recognise my project?
they are both in the same solution and I have already looked at similar questions and they are both already on the same framework so it isn't that.
I will add some pictures below to explain better and it is on BitBucket if you would like the link.





any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Your ASETests project is probably missing a reference to the ASE-Final-Project project, try following this answer

@AlexanderFreyr that's great thank you! That was definitely part of the problem. Would you know why Expression would still have a red line though? It says "Expression is inaccessible due to its protection level" would you know how to fix that?

@AlexanderFreyr Nevermind I've done it! I needed to make the internals visible in the assembly info :)

Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! See can I answer my own question, Just a reminder :)

So it was a little complicated but I needed to reference ASETests in the final project (or maybe the other way round :) ) and then I had to make the internals visible in the assembly info :)
I used this question mainly :) How to use a class from one C# project with another C# project?
